How do you call polygons whose vertices are scalar multiples of the roots of unity?
Is there a standard name for the family of polygons that are non-self-intersecting, have no holes, and whose vertices lie within the closed unit disc centered at the origin of the complex plane, being scalar multiples of the roots of unity?
More precisely, do we have a standard name for the family of d-gons whose vertices are
$(a_{0}  \zeta_0, \, \ldots, \, a_{d-1} \zeta_{d-1})$, with $a_k \in (0,1]$, $\zeta^d=1$, and $(\zeta_0, \, \ldots, \, \zeta_{d-1})$ being ordered counterclockwise?

No, there is no standard name for these polygons.

If you wanted to make up a name, I'd suggest something that reflects that the angles between vertices are distributed evenly around the origin.

I suggest a name : web-like polygons.
